# Difference between frames and items in libsndfile?

Tags: c, audio-processing, libsndfile

I am writing a software which processes audio files. I am using libsndfile library for reading wave file data, and I come across a doubt that wasn't solved by their documentation: what is the difference between functions that read items and functions that read frames? Or, in other words, am I getting the same results if I interchange both `sf_read_short` and `sf_readf_short`?

I have read in some questions that an audio frame equals a single sample, so I thought that what libsndfile calls items might be the same thing. During my tests they seemed to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was concerned too and found the answer.

> Q12 : **I'm looking at sf_read*. What are items? What are frames?**
>
> An item is a single sample of the data type you are reading; ie a
>   single short value for sf_read_short or a single float for
>   sf_read_float. For a sound file with only one channel, a frame is the
>   same as a item (ie a single sample) while for multi channel sound
>   files, a single frame contains a single item for each channel.
>
> Here are two simple, correct examples, both of which are assumed to be
>   working on a stereo file, first using items:
>
> ```
>     #define CHANNELS 2
>     short data [CHANNELS * 100] ;
>     sf_count items_read = sf_read_short (file, data, 200) ;
>     assert (items_read == 200) ;
> ```
>
> and now readng the exact same amount of data using frames:
>
> ```
>     #define CHANNELS 2
>     short data [CHANNELS * 100] ;
>     sf_count frames_read = sf_readf_short (file, data, 100) ;
>     assert (frames_read == 100) ;
> ```

This is a copy&paste from:
[libsndfile FAQ](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/FAQ.html), question 12.